# How to manipulate mat-card-header-text class for different mat-card elements?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This `mat-card-header-text` manipulates padding value of header text.I have two dfferent cards and I want to apply different margin for them.(default margin :0 16px)

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

This is the way how I can manipulate them.But is being applied for all.How to manipulate this for different cards?I want default `margin:0 16px;` for some of them and `0px` for another card element.Unfortunately without using this class name it doesnt apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some custom class to mat-card-header component and combine that class with mat-card-header-text

**component.html**

```
<mat-card-header class="header">
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
```

**component.css**

```
::ng-deep .header .mat-card-header-text {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Angular material selector in any other div element with some class. then you can style only within that particular div.

```
div .mat-card-header-text  {}
```